# Complex query in Elasticsearch with Spring Boot data version 8.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

How is possible translate this Elasticsearch query that works correctly in Postman to Spring Boot data version 8.x?

```json
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": [ "sample_id", "data_type","cancer_code"],
        "excludes": [ "expressions" ]
    },    
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "expressions",
            "inner_hits": 
            {
                "_source": [ "expressions.key", "expressions.value" ]
            },
            "query": 
            {
                "match":{ "expressions.key": "SMU1" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should return the same data as Postman does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```java
Query queryNested = NestedQuery.of(n -> n
    .path("expressions")
    .innerHits(InnerHits.of(in -> in.source(SourceConfig.of(sc -> 
            sc.filter(f -> f.includes(List.of("expressions.key", "expressions.value")))))))
    .query(MatchQuery.of(m -> m.field("expressions.key").query("SMU1"))._toQuery()))._toQuery();

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder()
    .source(SourceConfig.of(s -> s
        .filter(f -> f
            .includes(List.of("sample_id", "data_type", "cancer_code"))
            .excludes(List.of("expressions")))))
    .query(queryNested)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer the problem is that I need the **query** SpringBooy Object to be used inside this command to recover the data (a lot of results) like this:

`template.searchScrollStart(1000, query, Object.class, index);`

Where template is: 

`private ElasticsearchOperations operations;
AbstractElasticsearchTemplate template = (AbstractElasticsearchTemplate)operations;`